# Missing number, treated as zero <to be read again> \c@list \item f or \item o

Tags: errors, lists

I sat for hours and couldn't figure out where am missing. I think the answer is simple but I am really stuck at it. Please help !!!

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \textwidth 316pt
    \begin{document}

    We number the properties by a double numbering technique,
such that it is easy to refer to them.

\begin{enumerate}
\item
The observed properties hold for all $S$--boxes.
We analyze if the output of an $S$--box can or cannot change
if one modifies the inputs of an $S$--box in the following way\nobreak\hspace{0.7mm}:
\begin{list}{(\alph{list})}{\itemsep 0mm}
\item fix the inputs $e$ and $f$E
\item one is allowed to change $c$ and $d$ to an arbitrary value $c'$ and $d'$
\item one changes the inputs $a$ and $b$ as described in the properties
\end{list}
\begin{description}{1.4.}
\item[1.1.]
$\neg (\forall  c,d,c',d',e,f : S_{i}(0,0,c,d,e,f) \not=  S_{i}(1,0,c',d',e,f) )$
\item[1.2.]
$\neg (\forall  c,d,c',d',e,f : S_{i}(0,1,c,d,e,f) \not=  S_{i}(1,1,c',d',e,f) )$
\item[1.3.]
$\forall  c,d,c',d',e,f : S_{i}(0,1,c,d,e,f) \not=  S_{i}(1,0,c',d',e,f)$
\item[1.4.]
$\forall  c,d,c',d',e,f : S_{i}(0,0,c,d,e,f) \not=  S_{i}(1,1,c',d',e,f)$
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

One more error am getting in above is (in the description): "LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item"  at following lines please help me with this. I will be very grateful.

Am trying for something like this: [image]

Comment: What is`{1.4}` on entering the environment supposed to be there for?

Comment: Why is this tagged `latex-2.09` when it clearly isn't?

Comment: You shouldn't usually need to use `list` directly in a document. What are you trying to do exactly? What is `\alph{list}` supposed to do?

Comment: Hello, @cfr I have uploaded a image of what am looking for. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're planning on using the `list` environment to create a list-like structure, you need to be familiar with its syntax. From [`source2e`](//www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (section **54 List, and related environments**, p 269):

> The generic commands for creating an indented environment – `enumerate`,
>   `itemize`, `quote`, etc – are:
>
> ```
> \list{<LABEL>}{<COMMANDS>} ... \endlist
> ```
>
> which can be invoked by the user as the `list` environment. The `LABEL` argument specifies item labeling. `COMMANDS` contains commands for changing the
>   horizontal and vertical spacing parameters.
>
> Each item of the environment is begun by the command `\item[ITEMLABEL]`
>   which produces an item labeled by `ITEMLABEL`. If the argument is missing, then
>   the `LABEL` argument of the `\list` command is used as the item label.
>   The label is formed by putting `\makelabel{<ITEMLABEL>}` in an `hbox` whose
>   width is either its natural width or else `\labelwidth`, whichever is larger. The `\list` command defines `\makelabel` to have the default definition:
>
> ```
> \makelabel{<ARG>} == BEGIN \hfil ARG END
> ```
>
> which, for a label of width less than `\labelwidth`, puts the label flushright, `\labelsep` to the left of the item’s text. However, `\makelabel` can be `\let` to another command by the `\list`'s `COMMANDS` argument.
>
> A `\usecounter{<foo>}` command in the second argument causes the counter
>   foo to be initialized to zero, and stepped by every `\item` command without an
>   argument. (`\label` commands within the list refer to this counter.)

It's important to note the last paragraph, where a `\usecounter{<counter>}` identifies the `counter` to be used with the list. You haven't *defined* a counter, although you do say it should be `list`.

Instead, let's define the counter to be `mylistcntr` and add `\usecounter{mylistcntr}` to the second argument for `list`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcounter{mylistcntr}

\begin{document}

We number the properties by a double numbering technique,
such that it is easy to refer to them.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  The observed properties hold for all $S$--boxes.
  We analyze if the output of an $S$--box can or cannot change
  if one modifies the inputs of an $S$--box in the following way:
  \begin{list}{(\alph{mylistcntr})}{\usecounter{mylistcntr}\itemsep 0mm}
    \item fix the inputs $e$ and $f$E
    \item one is allowed to change $c$ and $d$ to an arbitrary value $c'$ and $d'$
    \item one changes the inputs $a$ and $b$ as described in the properties
  \end{list}
  \begin{description}
    \item[1.1.]
    $\neg (\forall  c,d,c',d',e,f : S_i(0,0,c,d,e,f) \neq S_i(1,0,c',d',e,f) )$
    \item[1.2.]
    $\neg (\forall  c,d,c',d',e,f : S_i(0,1,c,d,e,f) \neq S_i(1,1,c',d',e,f) )$
    \item[1.3.]
    $\forall  c,d,c',d',e,f : S_i(0,1,c,d,e,f) \neq S_i(1,0,c',d',e,f)$
    \item[1.4.]
    $\forall  c,d,c',d',e,f : S_i(0,0,c,d,e,f) \neq S_i(1,1,c',d',e,f)$
  \end{description}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

For a left-aligned enumeration (a), (b), ... you can use

```
\begin{list}
  {(\alph{mylistcntr})}
  {\usecounter{mylistcntr}%
   \def\makelabel#1{\rlap{#1}\hss}% Left-aligned label
   \itemsep 0mm}
```

You'll also note the following changes (some cosmetic, others not):

1. `\not=` is similar to `\neq` (fewer keystrokes).
2. `S_{i}` is similar to `S_i` (fewer keystrokes)
3. `description` is already defines as a `list` environment, and therefore doesn't take any additional arguments.

Comment: I've seen the gurus state that `S_i` is not official syntax and it should be `S_{i}`.  People who type the former tend to end up wondering why `S_ij` doesn't do what they expect ....

Comment: @cfr: True; use `S_{i}` when in doubt.

Answer (score 7):

Your environments are enumerate environments really. Load `enumitem` and everything will be simple:

```
\documentclass{report}
\textwidth 316pt
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist[enumerate]{wide = 0pt, leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

We number the properties by a double numbering technique,
such that it is easy to refer to them.

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*., wide, leftmargin=*]
\item
The observed properties hold for all $S$--boxes.
We analyze if the output of an $S$--box can or cannot change
if one modifies the inputs of an $S$--box in the following way\,:

 \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*), noitemsep]%
 \item fix the inputs $e$ and $f$.
 \item one is allowed to change $c$ and $d$ to an arbitrary value $c'$ and $d'$.
 \item one changes the inputs $a$ and $b$ as described in the properties.
 \end{enumerate}
%
 \begin{enumerate}[label=\theenumi\arabic*., wide=0pt]
 \item
 $\neg (\forall c,d,c',d',e,f : S_{i}(0,0,c,d,e,f) \not= S_{i}(1,0,c',d',e,f) )$
 \item
 $\neg (\forall c,d,c',d',e,f : S_{i}(0,1,c,d,e,f) \not= S_{i}(1,1,c',d',e,f) )$
 \item
 $\forall c,d,c',d',e,f : S_{i}(0,1,c,d,e,f) \not= S_{i}(1,0,c',d',e,f)$
 \item%
 $\forall c,d,c',d',e,f : S_{i}(0,0,c,d,e,f) \not= S_{i}(1,1,c',d',e,f)$
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]